# Laravel: How to redirect to post page

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, post, routes

I have a two step validation form, that means the first user input gets validated (within a ValidateTicketData-Controller) and if everything's correct you get to the next form page, which I get to by

```
Route::post('/{locale?}/ticket/{cat?}', 'TicketController@store')->name('validation');
```

Problem: On the second page the user is required to upload a file, if he doesn't the validation fails.
If this is the case the validator class immediately redirects which doesn't work since it's a post-route.

So I created a get route like this:

```
Route::get('/{locale?}/ticket/{cat?}', 'TicketController@store')->name('validation');
```

and put this in the `store`-method:

```
$ticketData = $request->validated();
if ($request->isMethod('get')) {
    $error = 'No pdf-file has been attached.';
    return view ('/validation', compact('ticketData', 'cat', 'error'));
}
```

I put this into the `store`-method because this is where the user gets redirected if he won't attach a file on the second page.

But if I now try to send the form without attaching a file I get the message that `I've redirected too many times`.

I can't find a solution how to redirect to the 'validation`-page with the validated input from the first page (because it gets displayed again) since the Validation class does it automatically.

**EDIT**

I changed the get-route to this:

```
Route::get('/{locale?}/ticket/{cat?}', function() {
  $error = 'no pdf tho.';
  return view('/validation', compact('error'));
});
```

and displayed the $error (if it's not empty) in the view. This worked, but I still don't know how to get the input data from the first page.

I also have this middleware for the `$locale`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   $locale = $request->segment(1);
   app()->setLocale($locale);
   return $next($request);
}
```

which seems to won't let me redirect sometimes, I don't really understand it

Comment: The store method is used for processing form data and redirecting accordingly. So, you are failing validation and going to process a form, this fails falidation and so on...

Comment: @ggdx have you got an idea how to prevent/solve this?

Comment: Yep. Use a more appropriate route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the problem is that after the first POST, you land on a new page where validation may fail, and if it does, it redirects back to itself (reloads) - which will fail because the POSTed data from the first step is now missing.

This is a common scenario, and the standard solution is to use [PRG - Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).  This means that after successfully processing a **P**OST, your code **R**edirects (with a **G**ET request) to a new page, rather than just returning that page's content.  This way if the user hits reload on the new page - or if validation on that new page fails - it just reloads (with GET) that new page, without resubmitting the POST.

In your case, that would look something like (I've used simplified URIs to keep things simple, and I may have mixed up your controller methods):

```
// GET the first page where user enters input
Route::get('/first-page-form', 'TicketController@showFirstPage');

// Handle that data being POSTed
Route::post('/first-page-processing', 'TicketController@store')->name('validation');
```

Now your `TicketController@store` method does its validation, and assuming everything passes, do *not* just return a view, but instead:

```
public function store(...) {
    // Validation code ...
    //
    // Assuming validation OK, save POSTed data to DB, or maybe
    // to session ...
    //
    // All done - redirect to a new page with a GET.
    return redirect('/next-page-form');
}
```

You'll need a GET route to handle that:

```
// GET the next page where user enters input
Route::get('/next-page-form', 'TicketController@showNextPage');

// And handle the next data being POSTed
Route::post('/next-page-processing', 'DatenTicketController@store');
```

If validation fails, it will simply redirect with GET back to `/next-page-form`.

Comment: When I add `Route::get('/{locale?}/ticket/{cat?}'); I get the error that this route has no action, what should I do?

Comment: @ofmiceandmoon Sorry, my mistake, I forgot to include the Controller@method.  I've updated my answer.  They are just normal GET routes, they need a URI and a Controller/method.

Comment: @ofmiceandmoon Does this help?

Comment: I was trying with your tips but somehow it still won't work. I think the middleware I've made for the localization gives me some issues

Comment: @ofmiceandmoon Try commenting it out temporarily to see if that is the issue?

Comment: Any luck @ofmiceandmoon? If I understand your problem correctly, PRG is the answer. You do need to store the first form's data between requests though, as I describe, eg in DB or session (or as query string parameters) ...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this with laravel Validation Class By making validation for handling validation response. You can follow below code for this.

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'validation1' => 'required',
    'validation2' => 'required',
    'validation3' => 'required',
]);

if ($validator->fails())
{
    redirect()->route('your route')->with('error',$validator->errors()->all());
    // or you can return response json for your some ajax or api calls
    return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
}

//do whatever on validation passes
// store data to database
return response()->json(['success'=>'Record is successfully added']);
```

You can read it from official documentation about it from here [manually-creating-validators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#manually-creating-validators)

Comment: if I have an `ValidateUploadedFile`- class that extends `FormRequest` how and where do I implement this then?

Comment: I don't have a `$validator` and I don't know where I could put this

Comment: you are making validator , see my code. and if in case you have your on validation class extends `FormRequest` then simply add validation like `'validation1'=> ValidateUploadedFile();`

Comment: @KaranSadana I think you misunderstood the problem.  The issue is that the user gets to the 2nd page via POST, so redirecting will not work.

Comment: @Don'tPanic you're right, I edited to question and added some code, but there's still the issue that I can't get the ticketData from the first input

Comment: @ofmiceandmoon  if you dont need redirecting then leave , i just explain how you stop autoredirecting of laravel validation and use as you want.